# convert vector of 4 bytes into int c++

Tags: c++, vector

my function read_address always returns a vector of 4 bytes

for other usecases it is a vector and not const array

in this use case I always return 4 bytes

```
std::vector<uint8_t> content;
 _client->read_address(start_addr, sizeof(int), content);
 uint32_t res = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(content.data());
 return res;
```

here is the vector called content
[image]

it is always the same values

however the value of "res" is always changing to random numbers
Can you please explain my mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is casting the pointer value (random address) to an integer instead of referencing what it points to.  Easy fix.

Instead of this:

```
uint32_t res = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(content.data());
```

This:

```
uint32_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(content.data());
uint32_t res = *ptr;
```

The language lawyers may take exception to the above.  And because there can be issues with copying data on unaligned boundaries on some platforms.  Hence, copying the 4 bytes out of content and into the address of the 32-bit integer may suffice:

```
memcpy(&res, content.data(), 4);
```

Comment: It's worth to mention that unless `uint8_t` is an alias to `unsigned char` or to `std::byte`, this violates the strict aliasing rule, thus invoking Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Fureeish -   I knew someone would call me out on that.  I updated the answer to suggest a memcpy approach.

Comment: language lawyers will complain about undefined behavior which is still lurking from this code.

Comment: @MarekR - tell me more. I'd like to be educated on this.

Comment: I would normally go for an endiannes-agnostic solution, especially since the original source of these bytes is not specified.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/199946/204571

Comment: What is interesting `msvc` sucks to optimize nicely a safe version of code: https://godbolt.org/z/TcM9Kc91W